# delete row according to condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of valid queue numbers.

```
valid_queues=[470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,490,497]
```

I want to remove the rows which has queue numbers NOT present in this list.

```
df.drop(df[df['Queue'] not in valid_queues].index, inplace = True)
```

The above code is giving an error :

> **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `df['Queue'] not in valid_queues` should be replaced with `~df['Queue'].isin(valid_queues)`